# SQL Query tuning

Tags: sql-server, performance

I just started learning query tuning and I am looking for some help with a question that was asked of me.  This query runs for hours if left as is, but I am told that a small change will make it run in a matter of moments.  I have tried several things but can't seem to make it do what I am looking for.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
SELECT     dt_ARRIVAL, s_PATIENT_FULL_NAME, n_ENCOUNTER_ID, s_VISIT_IDENT, dbo.fn_CheckIfRV(n_ENCOUNTER_ID, dt_ARRIVAL) AS RV, dt_DEPARTURE, 
                  s_OUTCOME_LOCATION, s_DispoLoc, s_LAST_ACUITY, s_COMPLAINT_FOR_SORT, s_DIAGNOSIS_FOR_SORT, s_GENDER, s_AGE, 
                  CASE WHEN Len(dbo.vw_RPT_ADHOC_DATA_DUMP.s_InitLabOrderList) > 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS LABv21, 
                  CASE WHEN Len(dbo.vw_RPT_ADHOC_DATA_DUMP.s_InitRadOrderList) > 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS RADv21
FROM         dbo.vw_RPT_ADHOC_DATA_DUMP
WHERE     (dt_ARRIVAL BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-08-13 00:00:00', 102) AND     CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-02-13 23:00:00', 102))
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the query plan to see what part of the query has the highest cost?

Comment: If `dt_ARRIVAL` is an actual `DATETIME` then no conversion is necessary, and that should save you some time.  Also, scalar functions are terribly slow.  If you can mimic the functionality in the query directly, that will save a ton of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT     dt_ARRIVAL, s_PATIENT_FULL_NAME, n_ENCOUNTER_ID, s_VISIT_IDENT, dbo.fn_CheckIfRV(n_ENCOUNTER_ID, dt_ARRIVAL) AS RV, dt_DEPARTURE, 
                  s_OUTCOME_LOCATION, s_DispoLoc, s_LAST_ACUITY, s_COMPLAINT_FOR_SORT, s_DIAGNOSIS_FOR_SORT, s_GENDER, s_AGE, 
                  CASE WHEN Len(dbo.vw_RPT_ADHOC_DATA_DUMP.s_InitLabOrderList) > 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS LABv21, 
                  CASE WHEN Len(dbo.vw_RPT_ADHOC_DATA_DUMP.s_InitRadOrderList) > 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS RADv21
FROM         dbo.vw_RPT_ADHOC_DATA_DUMP, 
       (select CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-08-13 00:00:00', 102)  as date_from, 
               CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-02-13 23:00:00', 102) as date_to) dates
WHERE     (dt_ARRIVAL BETWEEN dates.date_from AND dates.date_to)
```

Try to execte the CONVERT just once, not for each row

Comment: The CONVERTs are applied to constants, not to column values. I doubt very much they would be executed for every row.

Answer (score 0):

Just judging by the "**vw**" in **dbo.vw_RPT_ADHOC_DATA_DUMP** it seems that the query is against a view, not a table. Have a look to the inner connect of the view and try to optimize it. Even if the view is optimized you may find that for this specific query you can take some simplifications.

Anyway we would need to see the code of the view to improve our answers, if it is really a view.